# Drawing an angled arrow pointing to text inside equation

Tags: equations, arrows, text

I am trying to insert arrows between the terms of an equation explaining the partial results achieved.
For example, in the following equation (I manually drew the arrows), `V_i \frac{g_m}{1+g_mR_s}` would give `I_d`, while `V_i \frac{g_m}{1+g_mR_s} R_d` would be equal to `V_{R_d}` and so on:
[image]

Could anyone help me come up with a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nested stack.  I introduce `\dnAr[<size>]{<label>}` to do so, where `<size>` is stuff like `\bigg` (the default).  In the 2nd example, I exercise the optional argument to `\dnAr`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\dnAr[2][\bigg]{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-0.3pt}{#1\vert}{%
    \stackengine{1pt}{\rotatebox{55}{$\leftarrow\mkern-2mu$}}{%
      \mkern-5mu\scriptscriptstyle#2}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}{U}{r}{F}{T}{S}%
}}
\begin{document}
\[
V_u = V_i \frac{g_m}{1 + g_m R_s} \dnAr{I_d} R_d \dnAr{V_{R_d}}(-1)\dnAr{V_u}
\]
\[
V_u = V_i \frac{g_m}{1 + g_m R_s} \dnAr{I_d} R_d \dnAr[\big]{V_{R_d}}(-1)\dnAr[]{V_u}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's a version with 45 degree angled arrow and a tighter under-label:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newcommand\dnAr[2][\bigg]{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackengine{-0.7pt}{#1\vert}{%
    \stackengine{-1pt}{\rotatebox{45}{$\leftarrow\mkern-1.5mu$}}{%
      \mkern-5mu\scriptscriptstyle#2}{U}{l}{F}{T}{S}}{U}{r}{F}{T}{S}%
}}
\begin{document}
\[
V_u = V_i \frac{g_m}{1 + g_m R_s} \dnAr{I_d} R_d \dnAr{V_{R_d}}(-1)\dnAr{V_u}
\]
\[
V_u = V_i \frac{g_m}{1 + g_m R_s} \dnAr{I_d} R_d \dnAr[\big]{V_{R_d}}(-1)\dnAr[]{V_u}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @RenatoArino You are most welcome.  I have added a variant that may be more to your taste.

Answer (score 2):

A Tikz version.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\arrd[1]{
    \tikz[baseline, inner xsep=-1cm]{
        \draw[->] (0,.4) -- (0,-.2) -- (-.1,-.3) node[below, font=\tiny] {#1};
    }\ % for spacing
}

\begin{document}

$V_u = V_i \frac{g_m}{1+g_mR_s} \arrd{$id$} R_d \arrd{$V_{R_d}$} (-1) \arrd{$V_u$}$

\end{document}
```